# Sort array list by numbers then by letters

Tags: c#, sorting

I have array list of strings:

`"1A", "12A", "12B", "6", "A", "5B", "B", "13"`.

If I do `myList.Sort();` then I get:

`"1A", "12A", "12B", "13", "5B", "6", "A", "B"`.

But what I need is first sort by numbers in front, then by letter:

`"1A", "5B", "6", "12A", "12B", "13", "A", "B"`.

I could use

```
public class CustomComparer : IComparer
{
    Comparer _comparer = new Comparer(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        // Convert string comparisons to int
        return _comparer.Compare(Convert.ToInt32(x), Convert.ToInt32(y));
    }
}
```

But it throws exception. How do I get what I need?

Comment: "it throws exception" is never enough information. What is the exception?

Comment: Since some of the strings contain letters you cannot convert them to `int`s without first removing the letters.

Comment: and what is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: Is it possible you are executing `Compare` on content ? That  *will*  throw an exception, as you can not convert to `int`, say, "5B".

Comment: Is there only 'A' and 'B' caracters?

Comment: No, A and B is just for example, it could be any text.

Comment: Then could the text have numbers at other locations like "ABC123" or "AB55CD"?  And if so how should it handle those cases?

Comment: I could be AB55CD. It should compare A,then B, then 5.

Comment: More specifically what should come first "AB200CD" or "AB32CD"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot simply pass a string `"1A"` or `"5B"` to `Convert.ToInt32(x)`, because it has a portion that is not part of an `Int32`.

Instead, you should first split the string into two parts - the digits and everything else, and do the comparison with tie breaks.

One way of doing it would be writing two helper methods, and then using LINQ's `OrderBy` and `ThenBy`:

```
static int ExtractPrefix(string s) {
    // Parse the digits and stop; return the number
}
static string ExtractSuffix(string s) {
    // Skip digits, and return everything else
}
...
var sorted = unsorted.OrderBy(ExtractPrefix).ThenBy(ExtractSuffix).ToList();
```

Comment: Finding the "border line" between digits and the rest of the string can be done in many different ways. It is a nice exercise to do independently.

Comment: I tried that by I get Error 1 'System.Collections.ArrayList' does not contain a definition for 'OrderBy' and no extension method 'OrderBy' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.ArrayList' could be found

Comment: @babboon You need to add `using System.Linq` at the top of your code, and either switch to `System.Collections.Generic.List<string>`, or add `.Cast<string>()` between `unsorted` and `.OrderBy()`, i.e. `unsorted.Cast<string>().OrderBy(ExtractPrefix).ThenBy(ExtractSuffix).ToList();`

Comment: It gave an error in static int ExtractPrefix(string s) when input contains no digits and it returns null, but in that case I added to return number 99999999 and it did the trick. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 6):

Your comparer is too simplistic. Your comparison needs to split each value into the number and the rest, then compare the numbers first, then the strings if they're equal. So it would be something like:

```
public sealed class NumberStringComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        return NumberString.Parse(x).CompareTo(NumberString.Parse(y));
    }


    private struct NumberString : IComparable<NumberString>
    {
        private readonly int? number;
        private readonly string text;

        private NumberString(int? number, string text)
        {
            this.number = number;
            this.text = text;
        }

        internal static NumberString Parse(string text)
        {
            // TODO: Find where the digits stop, parse the number
            // (if there is one), call the constructor and return a value.
            // (You could use a regular expression to separate the parts...)
        }

        public int CompareTo(NumberString other)
        {
            // TODO: Compare numbers; if they're equal, compare
            // strings
        }
    }
}
```

If you have problems with either of the TODOs (*after* spending some time trying), you can ask for more specific help - but this is the general approach I'd use.

Comment: @Johnbot: Yes, will fix.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
public class CustomComparer : IComparer<string> {
  Comparer _comparer = new Comparer(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

  public int Compare(string x, string y) {
     string numxs = string.Concat(x.TakeWhile(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray());
     string numys = string.Concat(y.TakeWhile(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray());

     int xnum;
     int ynum;
     if (!int.TryParse(numxs, out xnum) || !int.TryParse(numys, out ynum)) {
        return _comparer.Compare(x, y);
     }
     int compareNums = xnum.CompareTo(ynum);
     if (compareNums != 0) {
        return compareNums;
     }
     return _comparer.Compare(x, y);
  }
}
```

Comment: Error 1 'string' does not contain a definition for 'TakeWhile' and no extension method 'TakeWhile' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found

Comment: add using System.Linq; in top of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Give this implementation a try?

http://www.dotnetperls.com/alphanumeric-sorting

From the link above:

```
public class AlphanumComparatorFast : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
    string s1 = x as string;
    if (s1 == null)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    string s2 = y as string;
    if (s2 == null)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    int len1 = s1.Length;
    int len2 = s2.Length;
    int marker1 = 0;
    int marker2 = 0;

    // Walk through two the strings with two markers.
    while (marker1 < len1 && marker2 < len2)
    {
        char ch1 = s1[marker1];
        char ch2 = s2[marker2];

        // Some buffers we can build up characters in for each chunk.
        char[] space1 = new char[len1];
        int loc1 = 0;
        char[] space2 = new char[len2];
        int loc2 = 0;

        // Walk through all following characters that are digits or
        // characters in BOTH strings starting at the appropriate marker.
        // Collect char arrays.
        do
        {
        space1[loc1++] = ch1;
        marker1++;

        if (marker1 < len1)
        {
            ch1 = s1[marker1];
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
        } while (char.IsDigit(ch1) == char.IsDigit(space1[0]));

        do
        {
        space2[loc2++] = ch2;
        marker2++;

        if (marker2 < len2)
        {
            ch2 = s2[marker2];
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
        } while (char.IsDigit(ch2) == char.IsDigit(space2[0]));

        // If we have collected numbers, compare them numerically.
        // Otherwise, if we have strings, compare them alphabetically.
        string str1 = new string(space1);
        string str2 = new string(space2);

        int result;

        if (char.IsDigit(space1[0]) && char.IsDigit(space2[0]))
        {
        int thisNumericChunk = int.Parse(str1);
        int thatNumericChunk = int.Parse(str2);
        result = thisNumericChunk.CompareTo(thatNumericChunk);
        }
        else
        {
        result = str1.CompareTo(str2);
        }

        if (result != 0)
        {
        return result;
        }
    }
    return len1 - len2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Link-only answers are generally frowned-upon in SO. This would have been better as a comment.

Comment: There I copied the IComparer implementation

Comment: While this may work, it looks considerably more complicated than it really needs to be.

Comment: Unless there is a compelling reason, I recommend `IComparer<T>` than `IComparer`.

Comment: Yeah I would agree Sriram, I honestly just grabbed the first thing I ran into for this guy.

Answer (score -1):

Below implementation of comparer should match your requirements:

```
public int Compare(string x, string y)
{
    var rx = new Regex("^(d+)");

    var xRes = rx .Match(x);
    var yRes = rx .Match(y);

    if (xRes.Success 
         && yRes.Success)
    {
        return int.Parse(xRes.Groups[1].Value).
               CompareTo(int.Parse(yRes.Groups[1].Value));
    }

    return x.CompareTo(y);
}
```

Comment: This would say that "123ABC" is equivalent to "123XYZ".  After parsing the numeric part, if the values are the same you have to then compare the alpha part.