# how can I sort a custom list depending on both integer and character value

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have a list of custom object, one property in this list is a string which can contain integers or integer and then a character. Like this:

```
1, 1A, 2, 3, 4, 4B, 4A
```

How can I sort this list so it sort according to this..

```
1, 1A, 2, 3, 4, 4A, 4B
```

I have checked the following link... [Sort array list by numbers then by letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30236585/sort-array-list-by-numbers-then-by-letters) but that only handle an array of string, mine is a list object with several properties..

This is my custom object list.

```
var myList = new List<Article>
{
    new Article {Position = "1", Info = "test1"},
    new Article {Position = "2", Info = "test2"},
    new Article {Position = "3", Info = "test3"},
    new Article {Position = "4", Info = "test4"},
    new Article {Position = "4B", Info = "test5"},
    new Article {Position = "4A", Info = "test6"}
};
```

Comment: I assume you want an in-place sort?

Comment: Have you tried to use var orderdlist = myList.Orderby(x=>x.Position)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm taking the custom `IComparer<T>` implemented by [@MehrzadChehraz in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30236923/1870803) (if this helps, make sure to give him the credit), and adding the missing piece which is simply to use the overload of `Enumerable.OrderBy` which takes a custom `IComparer<T>`:

```
void Main()
{
    var myList = new List<Article>
    {
        new Article {Position = "1", Info = "test1"},
        new Article {Position = "2", Info = "test2"},
        new Article {Position = "3", Info = "test3"},
        new Article {Position = "4", Info = "test4"},
        new Article {Position = "4B", Info = "test5"},
        new Article {Position = "4A", Info = "test6"}
    };

    var sortedList = myList.OrderBy(x => x.Position, new CustomComparer()).ToList();
}

public class CustomComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    Comparer _comparer = new Comparer(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        string numxs = string.Concat(x.TakeWhile(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray());
        string numys = string.Concat(y.TakeWhile(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray());

        int xnum;
        int ynum;
        if (!int.TryParse(numxs, out xnum) || !int.TryParse(numys, out ynum))
        {
            return _comparer.Compare(x, y);
        }
        int compareNums = xnum.CompareTo(ynum);
        if (compareNums != 0)
        {
            return compareNums;
        }
        return _comparer.Compare(x, y);
    }
}
```

Which yields:

[image: Result from LINQPad]

Comment: Note that `OrderBy` Creates a new sequence that you're not assigning back to any variable.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Not sure why creating a custom comparer is complicated? I think your answer will definitely be more performant one, doing an in place sort, but I'm not sure I'd call it simple.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I think my solution is the simplest compared to the other two.

Comment: It's simple in that it really only has one line of actual code: `self.Sort((lhs, rhs) => StrCmpLogicalW(stringSelector(lhs), stringSelector(rhs)));`

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yes, but It has a hidden assumption that the OP is familiar with PInvoke, which I'm not sure is the case.

Comment: Remember to fix your answer btw: It should be `myList = myList.OrderBy(x => x.Position, new CustomComparer()).ToList();` otherwise the results will be discarded.

Answer (score 0):

First we can define a list extension for "natural sorting", using the Windows API method [`StrCmpLogicalW()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759947(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
public static class ListExt
{
    [DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(string lhs, string rhs);

    // Version for lists of any type.
    public static void SortNatural<T>(this List<T> self, Func<T, string> stringSelector)
    {
        self.Sort((lhs, rhs) => StrCmpLogicalW(stringSelector(lhs), stringSelector(rhs)));
    }

    // Simpler version for List<string>
    public static void SortNatural(this List<string> self)
    {
        self.Sort(StrCmpLogicalW);
    }
}
```

You can then in-place sort your list like so:

```
myList.SortNatural(x => x.Position);
```

Note: You don't need the `public static void SortNatural(this List<string> self)` method for this example, but I included it for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

For Simplicity, you can use Regex in combination with Linq:

```
Regex rgxNumber = new Regex(@"\d+");
Regex rgxCharacters = new Regex("[a-zA-Z]+");

Func<string, int> getNumberPart = str => int.Parse(rgxNumber.Match(str).ToString());
Func<string, string> getCharactersPart = str => rgxCharacters.Match(str).ToString();

var orderd = myList.OrderBy(x => getNumberPart(x.Position))
                   .ThenBy(x => getCharactersPart(x.Position)).ToList();
```

This assumes no data in the form `1B2` is present.